# Mysql records pull and added into php array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my static array data:

```
$order = \EasyPost\Order::create(array(
    "from_address" => $from_address,
    "to_address" => $to_address,
    "shipments" => array(
        array(
            "parcel" => array("length" => 12.0, "width" => 10.5, "height" => 6.8, "weight" => 12),
         
        ),
        array(
            "parcel" => array("length" => 11.9, "width" => 10.0, "height" => 7.3, "weight" => 18),
            
        ),
    ),
));
```

I am trying pull parcel data  from database and add into the array:

```
$parcels = array();
    while($box = mysqli_fetch_assoc($boxInfo))
    {
        $weight = $box["box_weight"];
        $distance_unit = $box["box_size_unit"];
        $mass_unit = $box["box_weight_unit"];
        $length = $box["package_length"];
        $width = $box["package_width"];
        $height = $box["packag_height"];
    
        $parcels[] = array(
        "length"  => $length, 
        "width" => $width, 
        "height" => $height, 
        "weight" => $weight);
    
    }
$order = \EasyPost\Order::create(array(
    "from_address" => $from_address,
    "to_address" => $to_address,
    "shipments" => array(
        array(
            "parcel" => array($parcels),
            ),
       
    ),
));
```

Seems is not working. Am I missing anything?

Comment: hi, it seems in the data each parcel needs to be enclosed in its own array with a `parcel` key containing a single array.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What happens now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$parcels[] = array (
                 'parcel' => array(
                                  "length"  => $length, 
                                  "width" => $width, 
                                  "height" => $height, 
                                  "weight" => $weight
                                  )
                  )
 ;
```

and then just assign to "shipments" key later

```
"shipments" => $parcels
```

if your intention is to get data as in the static data example.